# Use deriv or D as part of a function

Tags: r

I have got the following problem. I am trying to compute a function like:

```
derivation <- function(function, number) {  
  derivation <- deriv(~function, "x")  
  return(derivation(number))  
}
```

For example:

```
derivation(x^2, 3) {  
  derivation <- 2*x  
  return(2*3)  
}
```

I don't care if I have to put the function in the beginning in braces or as an expression. The variable will always be `x`. Also be open to use `D`.

Comment: so you want the function itself to be passed as an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
f <- function(fun,val) {
   expr <- substitute(fun)
   d <- deriv(expr,"x",function.arg=TRUE)
   g <- attr(d(val),"gradient")
   return(g)
}
f(x^2,3)
```

- `substitute()` converts the argument `fun` to an expression *without* evaluating it
- `deriv(...,function.arg=TRUE)` returns a function that computes the value and includes the derivative as an attribute
- `d(val)` calls the function
- `attr(.,"gradient")` extracts the gradient

If you want to return both the function value and its gradient (as a two-element vector), you could use

```
r <- d(val)
return(c(c(r),attr(r,"gradient"))
```

in the function (the internal `c(r)` drops the attributes from `r`).

Comment: That's marvellous, close to functional programming! Never know this is possible in R!

Comment: That's great! Is it possible to use fun in the function like:  t<-fun(val)  return(g,t) ?